# Is the "_" character in the first anonymous function a wildcard?

Tags: f#

Given this function

```
let readInput() = 
  Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> Console.ReadLine())
 |> Seq.takeWhile (fun s -> s <> null) `
 |> Seq.map int`
```

is the `_` in the function called by `Seq.initInfinite` a wild card, so that anything can be read off STDIN?

I've got a couple of different F# books, and am looking on the Internet, but can only find references to `_` being used in unpacking tuple values.

Comment: Not quite. `Seq.initInfinite` expects to be passed a function of type ` int-> 'T`, which it then calls multiple times with an increasing index. In this case, the function we want it to call is  `fun _ -> Console.ReadLine()`, ie a function that ignores its parameter and returns a string from `Console.ReadLine()`. `_` can be used anywhere that you want a "throw-away" variable or parameter, ie one that gets assigned, but is never read, as above. In that regard it's very similar to the `_` in wildcard patterns.

Comment: @DavidArno Thank you for confirming that "_" acts very much like when Clojure parameters are destructured and the binding isn't important. I often use "_" when I want a function to execute. Thanks, cmn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is the `_` in the function called by `Seq.initInfinite` a wild card

[Yes.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#wildcard-pattern)

> so that anything can be read off STDIN

No. [`Seq.initInfinite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.initinfinite%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) passes an `int`, indicating the current index. For example, you can use it to create an infinite sequence of only even numbers: `Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i * 2)`. 
But in your case, you don't care about the index, so using `_` is appropriate here.

Using the wildcard here does not affect the `Console.ReadLine()` in any way.

Answer (score 2):

"Don't care" underscore identifiers are effectively used as wildcard patterns. The difference with a variable that would happen to be named `_` is that each occurrence of `_`  represents a different identifier; consequently: (1) you can't reference the same `_` twice and thus (2) no warning is emitted for lack of usage of `_`, whereas another name like `dummy` would probably raise a warning for never being used.

The don't care symbol is is present in languages with built-in pattern matching because sometimes you only want to match a value against a particular structure and the actual content is not important. This happens mostly in F#, OCaml, Haskell and notably Prolog, but other languages might provide this too.

Here is a simplistic example in OCaml:

```
let empty = function [] -> true | _ :: _ -> false;;
```

Here above, you just want to match empty lists vs. non-empty lists. You have two different patterns to dissociate both cases, but the actual content of non-empty lists won't be used, so you just place  underscores.

See also section [2.4 Identifiers and Operators](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4) of Haskell specification:

> However, “_” all by itself is a reserved identifier, used as wild card in patterns.

Thanks to [svick's comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331553/is-the-character-in-the-first-anonymous-function-a-wildcard/331560#comment706388_331554), I don't have to search much for the [relevant quote](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#wildcard-pattern) for [f#](/questions/tagged/f%23):

> Wildcard Pattern
>
> The wildcard pattern is represented by the underscore (_) character
>   and matches any input, just like the variable pattern, except that the
>   input is discarded instead of assigned to a variable. The wildcard
>   pattern is often used within other patterns as a placeholder for
>   values that are not needed in the expression to the right of the ->
>   symbol. The wildcard pattern is also frequently used at the end of a
>   list of patterns to match any unmatched input.